# Sample OData service with service operations?

Tags: wcf, odata

The services.odata.org/odata/odata.svc one has a single service operation, but I'm looking for one which takes parameters of different types. I would at least like to see one which takes strings, but guids and dates would be nice as well.

Thanks

Comment: odata is for REST operations. Rest doesn't take "parameters". Are you looking for how to do SOAP?

Comment: I don't really know actually. I do know that OData supports something called "service Operations" which are stored procedures that are evaluated on the back end, and the results are made available via the producer. see: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/operations/#213_Invoking_Service_Operations if my response doesn't make sense.

Comment: How about you describe you ACTUAL problem and why you think OData is the right solution. :) Hopefully we can figure out what the best solution for you is...

Comment: I'm writing a database connector for my work. I don't need OData to do anything, I just need a service to test against. I don't even need the code for it, just one that is hosted somewhere that I can mess with.

Comment: Okay...let me rephrase that. What is your problem, without bringing in OData. Are you trying to expose your database to a client via HTTP? How is CRUD access mediated in your database, via DML statements (like Insert/Select/Update/Delete) or via sprocs? What technology does your client use? What technology does your server use?